# Capture "Form Data" instead of querystring in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying something different to check if it is feasible. Otherwise best alternative way is to send data using querystring.

1. I have a html page which has list of students. when user clicks on perticular student for edit, this html page should take student ID and redirect to another html page, which will load respective student details for editing.
2. Here, I want to send data using **"POST"** method to hide studentID from URL (querystring), so I created a hindden form (method="POST" action="edit.html")on list html and put one hidden field under it. on lcik of edit button on list, I am setting value to hidden field & submitting form.
3. Now this redirects properly to edit html page and also when I see this flow in chrome developer tool, I can see this form value under headers sections - Form data. Now I am trying to fectch this form data on edit html page load e.g. in JQuery under document ready function or simple in javascript.
4. with alternative option if I create hindden form (method="GET" action="edit.html") then the hidden field value which I am setting is showing up in query string and also in chrome developer tool, it is showing under headers - query string parameters. This query string parameters can easily be accessed using location.search and then play around and will get expected value.
5. Here id I have taken just example, however in actual scenario, I need to send multiple values or may be objects which I dont want send thrugh query string. So I thought to submit form with POST method and retrive values on next HTML page load thrugh javascript on jquery.

**HTML**

```
<form style="display: none" action="jquerywebapidoestudenteditpoc.html" method="post" id="formEdit"> <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="" /> </form>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).on("click", ".edit", function () { var id = $(this).data("id"); $("#id").val(id); event.preventDefault(); $("#formEdit").submit(); });
```

[image: Chrome Developer tool capture]

If anyone came accross this situation or implemented it in very appropriate way, would be very good.

In other words, I would like to implement is:

1. list.html will post data to server (`.NET Web API`)
2. At same time list.html will redirect to edit.html
3. On load of edit.html, response from server will be loaded on page.

Comment: show us your jquery code/

Comment: I don't believe you'll be able to read form/post data on a subsequent page in this way.  It would normally be dealt with by the server, and any action taken there with the results injected into the response of the next page.

Comment: Note that `POST` requests are not assumed to be safe, hence many browsers will prompt you about re-posting data (or simply fail to do so) when you reload the page. As opposed to `GET`, where by convention you should be able to send the same request several times without causing any changes.

Comment: @JamesThorpe, I am implementing this through `jQuery` & `.NET Web API`. It would be great if you can give me any pointer, how this can be achived, as per your comment. I will take it from there.

Comment: @Avinash You probably want to [start here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms525985(v=vs.90).aspx) then - this is a collection containing the data posted from the first page.

Comment: After doing more digging, what I am trying to achieve is already there in `.NET MVC`, where action mehod returns `IActionResult View(MODEL)`. So this thing internally handled by MVC framework. However I still not able to understand or got confused, how this will be achieved using `JQuery & .NET Web API`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bsically, what I understood after going through lot many blogs ans sites, I have to have a client controller (javascript based) which will take care of which view has to load and post data. 
This I was able to achieve using AngularJS, where I can configuration can be done for routing and by same, I can post data & receive its whatever output on another view/ form (so called page).

e.g.

```
$routeProvider.when("/orders", {
        controller: "ordersController",
    templateUrl: "/app/views/orders.html"
});
```

AngularJS Rocks !!!

Answer (score 1):

Query string is part of the "identifier" of the subsequently loaded page (or any other resource). As such, it is accessible from the page. Data sent in the body of a POST request are different - they are meant for the server only and are inaccessible from the subsequently loaded page.

However, if you wish to make the data sent using POST available to the next page, you can always inject it into the page manually. Using PHP (as an example), it could look something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var postData = <?php json_encode($_POST); ?>;
</script>
```

---

If you just want to pass data from one page to another and leave the server out of it, you may either use `GET` (query string) for exposed communication or use cookies for "hidden" communication.

Comment: This all I am doing in plain `HTML/JQuery` can be considered as `VIEW` and don't want to use `PHP or ASP` language piece.

Comment: @Avinash My answer seems exhaustive to me. `POST` is meant for interaction with the server. If you don't control the server, don't use `POST`. If you want hidden inter-page communication, you might want to look into using cookies. (I've edited my answer to include this.)